# Bootstrap date picker displays Undefined Nan as header in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

We are using bootstrap date picker plugin for displaying calendar. This date field is editable. So, if I give a value like 10-10-19 manually, then the calendar is displayed with "Undefined Nan" as header and not able to select another date from date picker calendar.

It accepts till year as 70 like (10-10-70). Below is the demo link we referred and we used it in our application. It is working fine in Chrome browser and accepts even 1 as year but not in Mozilla Firefox.  How can I resolve this?

[Bootstrap date picker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

Comment: can anyone please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

Add this script:

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dateonly: true,
    yearRange: '1950:2013',
});

$("#StartDate").datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd/mm/yy');
```

Comment: Hi Pramod. We follow date format: MM-DD-YYYY. If I edit date value manually as (10-10-9), then the datepicker header is displayed as Undefined Nan and not allowing me to select any date from datepicker there until unless i manually enter valid year with 3 digits. it is accepting till 70 like (MM-DD-YYYY as 11-05-70). But it is not accepting before it like 11-05-69 and below years and showing Undefined Nan                                $('#endDate').datepicker({
                     format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
                     autoclose: true
                 });

Comment: i have update code add yearrange in script for mm/dd/yy replace it to dd/mm/yy

Comment: This bootstrap datepicker is working fine in Chrome browser but not in Mozilla Firefox. Can anyone help me? Still it is showing undefined Nan in Firefox only but not in Chrome browser

Comment: let me know if you remove datepicker make it text what value you get on browser

Comment: I am getting this same issue. Did you ever resolve it? Datepicker works fine in local environment on both Chrome and Firefox. In live doesn't work on Firefox but OK on Chrome. Globalisation settings same between environments. Format of date value in datepicker's text input element identical between environments. If anyone has solved this please let me know.

Comment: Ah, it would appear this was a known issue which has been fixed in more recent versions. Latest version here works fine - https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/